# How to use variables in ax.set_title and fig.savefig

Tags: python

I goal is to plot a figure and give it a title and save it as png file.

For example, I plot a figure first

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from skimage import measure


# Set up mesh
n = 100

x = np.linspace(-3,3,n)
y = np.linspace(-3,3,n)
z = np.linspace(-3,3,n)
X, Y, Z =  np.meshgrid(x, y, z)

# Create cardioid function
def f_heart(x,y,z):
    F = 320 * ((-x**2 * z**3 -9*y**2 * z**3/80) +
               (x**2 + 9*y**2/4 + z**2-1)**3)
    return F

# Obtain value to at every point in mesh
vol = f_heart(X,Y,Z)

# Extract a 2D surface mesh from a 3D volume (F=0)
verts, faces ,_ ,_ = measure.marching_cubes_lewiner(vol, 0, spacing=(0.1, 0.1, 0.1))


# Create a 3D figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Plot the surface
ax.plot_trisurf(verts[:, 0], verts[:,1], faces, verts[:, 2],
                cmap='Spectral', lw=1)

# Change the angle of view and title
ax.view_init(15, -15)
```

Now, I want to use a variable as a title to the plot and save it as png file.

```
#set the number of variable Θ
Θ = 1

#give the title
ax.set_title("Θ = ", fontsize=25)


plt.show()
fig.savefig('D:/Θ = .png')
```

I hope this code can give me a plot with title Θ = 1 (or other value that I set for Θ), and save the plot at D:/ with a name Θ = 1.

How can I edit my code to achieve this?
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add theta variable to title string

```
theta = 1
ax.set_title("Θ = %.i" % theta, fontsize=25)
```

By saving file do the same

```
fig.savefig('Θ = ' + str(theta) +'.png')
```

Comment: Could you also teach me how to do when theta = pi/2 ? ( a float number)

Comment: @Joanne you mean set pi/2 as symbol in title?

Comment: yes~ I would like to have a title 'Θ = pi/2'. And also a file named Θ = pi/2.png

Comment: @Joanne `ax.set_title("$\Theta$ = $\pi/2$", fontsize=25)` but you can't save file  with name that contains `/`

Comment: @Joanna if my answer was helpful, will be nice if you give my arrow up :)

Comment: Sure~ I will~~~